# Show that $f(x) = x^TQx$ is convex using the inequality $f(y+\alpha(x-y))-\alpha f(x)-(1-a)f(y)\le 0$

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, quadratic-forms, positive-semidefinite

> Suppose that $f(x) = x^TQx$, where $Q$ is $n\times n$ symmetric
>   positive semidefinite matrix. Show that $f(x)$ is convex on the domain
>   $\mathbb{R}^n$. Hint: it may be convenient to prove the following
>   equivalent inequality: $$f(y+\alpha(x-y))-\alpha f(x)-(1-a)f(y)\le 0$$
>   for all $\alpha\in[0,1]$

**UPDATE**: I redid the calculations:

I did and tried to prove it's $\le0$ by the following:

$$(y^T + ax^T-ay^T)(Qy+aQx-aQy) - ax^TQx-(1-a)y^TQy = \\y^TQy + ay^TQx-ay^TQy+ax^TQy+a^2x^TQx-a^2x^TQy -ay^TQy -a^2y^TQx +a^2y^TQy- ax^TQx -(1-a)y^TQy = \\(1-2\alpha+\alpha^2-1+a)y^tQy + (\alpha^2-\alpha) x^tQx+(\alpha+\alpha-\alpha^2-\alpha^2)y^tQx =\\ (-2\alpha+\alpha^2+a)y^tQy+(\alpha^2-\alpha)x^tQx+(2\alpha + 2\alpha^2)y^tQx$$

But I still don't see why this should be less than $0$. We have that $y^tQy$ and $x^tQx$ are positive semidefinite matrices. However I don't know how to deal with the term $y^tQx$

Comment: How can $y^TQx+x^TQy\le 0$ for all $x,y,$ and symmetric positive semidefinite $Q$? Take $Q=I$ and $x=y$.

Comment: @OliverJones so if they're not negative, then it's a lot harder to prove what I want. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Firstly, you're mixing $\alpha$ and $a$ in your question. Secondly, the calculation can be simplified by assuming $Q$ is diagonal.

Comment: Also, there's a mistake in the first line of your calculation. $-a^2y^TQy$ should be  $a^2y^TQy$. There's another mistake in the last line. Re-do the calculation.

Comment: Can you explain please why have you expanded it as such $(y^T + ax^T-ay^T)(Qy+aQx-aQy)$? That's the only step I am struggling with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, $a=\alpha$ (from the definition of a convex function).

Secondly, you still have a minor sign typo in the last line. It should be
$$
(-2\alpha+\alpha^2+a)y^tQy+(\alpha^2-\alpha)x^tQx+(2\alpha \color{red}- 2\alpha^2)y^tQx.
$$
With these corrections being done, the last line becomes
$$
(\alpha^2-\alpha)y^tQy-2(\alpha^2-\alpha)y^tQx+(\alpha^2-\alpha)x^tQx=(\alpha^2-\alpha)\cdot (x-y)^tQ(x-y)
$$
which is $\le 0$ since $(\alpha^2-\alpha)\le 0$ for $\alpha$ in the interval.

Comment: I'm doing the calculations again and I always find $(\alpha^2-\alpha)y^tQy$, are you sure about your result? The rest I found is the same

Comment: Now I see, the line you wrote was mine, but you corrected only the minus sign error, and left the other error there, but you actually used the right expression for your answer

Comment: Actually it wasn't an error, now I see it better